# Powershell Script to Create Outlook 2019 Personal Folder

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, outlook

Currently users have their own inbox folder and due to corporate policy emails will automatically be deleted after a set period of time.
Some emails however users would like to be able to keep for reference.

In order to accomplish allowing users to keep their importasnt emails; a personal folder file .pst needs to be created. The deletion policy will on affect the exchange profile folder that they currently use. This special personal folder should not be touched by the corporate system.

I need to be able to run a powershell script to automatically create this folder for the user (logged in user on the computer) and assign it in outlook 2019 for use, the user will then copy their specific emails into that personal folder. If I can't do it for the current logged in user - then by a collection of usernames and put in their one drive folder ??

Anyone with knowledge of how to or code to do this, I would appreciate your help - while I can code - I'am not a Powershell Guru so specifics and functions that experts might know exactly - I do not know, so please in your answer provide good guidance.

I am using windows 10 .1909 and the powershell version that ships with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [AddStoreEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstoreex) method which adds a Personal Folders file (.pst) in the specified format to the current profile.

```
Sub CreateUnicodePST()  
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace   
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 myNameSpace.AddStoreEx "c:\" & myNameSpace.CurrentUser & "\.pst",olStoreUnicode  
End Sub
```

After creating additional storage in the Outlook profile users can move items for keeping them locally. Or you may consider creating a VBA script or COM add-in for doing that programmatically. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for getting started quickly.

Comment: The question requested Powershell , " I need to be able to run a powershell script to automatically create this folder for the user".